# Apache not serving Django on 443 (aws)

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app I'm trying to serve over HTTPS and struggling. I'm not strong in Apache configs and trying to piece this together. Hopefully somebody can point out what seems like a simple oversight.

My certificate is set up and when I visit my site at `http://` it redirects to `https://` with a valid cert issued by Amazon. So, that seems to be correct.

**MY PROBLEM**

I just see a page with:

## Index of /

### EDIT #1:

More experimenting shows that without any of the additional `.conf` files I get django on `http` and `https` as expected. If I enable just the `*.80` redirect, I always get `https` as intended but just the apache index page as mentioned above without django.

Here are my configs that get written with container commands:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf** (which gets rewritten by aws each deployment)

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/www/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/www/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/proof/proof/wsgi.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=3 threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>

LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhost_http.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhost_https.conf** (optional. I get the same result with or without this file)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/www/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/www/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/proof/proof/wsgi.py process-group=wsgi

<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

### EDIT #2:

**Here is the best evidence I have of what VHosts are happening**

```
[ec2-user@ip-000-00-00-000 conf.d]$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1024 May 16 06:56 enable_mod_deflate.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 May 15 23:10 healthd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  104 May 15 23:10 mod_reqtimeout.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  783 May 16 06:56 wsgi.conf
[ec2-user@ip-000-00-00-000 conf.d]$ apachectl -S
[Thu May 16 07:22:36.788065 2019] [so:warn] [pid 24579] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-000-00-00-000.us-west-2.compute.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhost_http.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ip-000-00-00-000.us-west-2.compute.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtualhost_http.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ip-000-00-00-000.us-west-2.compute.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf:7)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48 not_used
Group: name="apache" id=48 not_used
```

**And here is evidence that the cert is working but is not connecting to Django**

```
(v-env) My-MacBook-Pro$ curl -v https://www.proofapp.io
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.proofapp.io/
*   Trying 50.112.160.41...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.proofapp.io (50.112.160.41) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.proofapp.io
*  start date: May 15 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 15 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.proofapp.io" matched cert's "www.proofapp.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.proofapp.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 07:28:17 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Content-Length: 161
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
<ul></ul>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host www.proofapp.io left intact
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gets rewritten by aws each deployment", what deployment?

Comment: when you run `eb deploy` and Elastic Beanstalk copies your application bundle and deploys it, this default wsgi.py gets copied into the directory. I don't think it can be altered?

Comment: Oh, sorry, elastic beanstalk is not something I can help with, let's wait for someone more versed

Comment: I think EB is a factor, but once it's there it's really just an apache issue, I think...

Comment: We can try. First, if your `virtualhost_https.conf` is optional (so even without it you can open homepage over https, even empty one), that means that there is another *:443 virtual host in one of your other .conf files. You need to find that and show us the content (and check if it gets affected by deployments)

Comment: It looks to my uneducated eye like my `*.80` redirect takes effect and ignores the `wsgi.conf` settings. Hence, when it goes to `*.443` it doesn’t know what to do. If my understanding is correct, why didn’t my `virtualhost_https.conf` file solve it?

Comment: Yes it ignores the wsgi.conf. the reason is that you have two virtual hosts, and only  the first (topmost) one is applied. And if they are in different files, then the one from (alphabetically) first file. But you don't really need wsgi.conf for :80, since you don't want to serve django over plain http

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193447/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-scott).

Answer (score 0):

Scott, not sure if you've since resolved this issue but I'll share additional perspective and strategies in the event you haven't - or for future readers.

A convenient way to address this issue is to utilize a Load Balancer for your SSL termination. This will mean no complex configs at the application level and will also provide performance boosts (and possible cost savings) by offloading HTTPS encryption/decryption processes to other AWS resources.

You can read more on these strategies and implementations at the links below. If you have additional questions I'd be happy to provide further details on specific steps.

[AWS Load Balancer Best Practices](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/aws-elastic-load-balancer-best-practices/)

[AWS SSL Termination Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/)